# The superclass 'BluetoothDevice ' doesn't have a zero argument constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and i want to use this code from a youtube tutorial

```
class _DeviceWithAvailability extends BluetoothDevice {
  BluetoothDevice device;
  _DeviceAvailability availability;
  int? rssi;

  _DeviceWithAvailability(this.device, this.availability, [this.rssi]);
}
```

but it giving an error

> The superclass 'BluetoothDevice ' doesn't have a zero argument constructor.

and suggestion

> Try declaring a zero argument constructor in 'BluetoothDevice ', or
> explicitly invoking a different constructor in 'BluetoothDevice '.

I read the documentation but it isn't clear to me.

Please help mo to solve this.

Comment: What's the package? I think that this error is related to BluetoothDevice device initialization.

Comment: package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your **BluetoothDevice device** initialization, because the constructor need many parameters that are mandatory, you have two solutions.

1.Initializate this variable with empty parameters like this:

```
BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothDevice(...);
```

2.Add **late** property and before use this var do you need to initialize with correct information, like this:

```
late BluetoothDevice device;
```

and then, before use this var you need to pass the correct information like this:

```
device = BluetoothDevice(...);
```

Comment: what does ... means, could you give me the whole code? I am very new to flutter...

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion means,

> A zero-argument constructor is literally a constructor that can be
> invoked with zero arguments. This includes constructors that take only
> optional arguments.

Some examples:

```
SomeClass();//this is zero argument constructor
SomeClass2(String argument1);//this is one argument constructor
SomeClass3(String argument1,String argument2);//this is 2 argument constructor
```